how to fix the frametitle override the beamer logo
I am trying to add a logo in the beamer, when I add the frame title, I found the logo was overrided by the frame title. how to make the transparent png shows in front of the frame title? This is the code look like:
\documentclass{ctexbeamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=2cm]{companylogo}{figure/logo.png}
\logo{\vspace*{8cm}\pgfuseimage{companylogo}}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{\fontsize{9pt}{14pt}\textbf{sub title}}
\author{jiangxiaoqiang}
\institute{CPU}
\date{\today}

%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{work}
hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}

on the second page, the logo did not show in the beamer. This is the logo:

what should I do to make the logo show in front of the frame title?

You could add your logo to a layer which is in front of the frame content, e.g. the footline:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0.25cm,fill=structure.fg] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{O9w6e9w1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{9pt}{14pt},series=\bfseries}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{sub title}
\author{jiangxiaoqiang}
\institute{CPU}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{work}
hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}


